# How to compare two arrays in JavaScript even if they aren't ordered?

Tags: javascript, arrays, meteor

This question has been asked so many times but I can't make what I want so I ask for your help.

I have 2 arrays `checkMyDataSources` and `lesInfosMachines`.

I need to run through `checkMyDataSources` to check if there is no occurrence of any items in `lesInfosMachines`.
The content of `checkMyDataSources` can be something like `["datasource_A","datasource_B","datasource_D","datasource_C"]` and the name is linked with the name of each item in `lesInfosMachines` who contains thing like `["A","B","C","D"]`.

The problem is that I'm not able to run through all the `checkMyDataSources`, I mean when the cell A and Amachine are different it call `createDataSource`despite Amachine is maybe in the cell D.

```
var lesInfosMachines = InfosMachines.find({});
    if(checkMyDataSources.length < 1){
      console.log("there is not datasource, we will create them all");
      callInitDS();
    }else{
      console.log("there is datasource, we will check them");
      lesInfosMachines.forEach(Meteor.bindEnvironment(function(machineInfo) {
        console.log("test machine " + machineInfo.nameMachine)
        for (var i = 0; i < checkMyDataSources.length; i++) {
          console.log("test on " + checkMyDataSources[i].name.split("_")[1]);

          if(checkMyDataSources[i].name.split("_")[1] === machineInfo.nameMachine){
            console.log("Datasource:  " + machineInfo.nameMachine + " already exist." );
          }else{
            if(machineInfo.ipAddr != null){
              console.log("going to create " + machineInfo.nameMachine);
              createDataSource(machineInfo.nameMachine, machineInfo.ipAddr);
            }else{
              console.log("going to create " + machineInfo.nameMachine + 
                          " with a fake @ip because it was null 
                            ONLY FOR TESTING WE NEED TO REMOVE THIS"
                         );
              createDataSource(machineInfo.nameMachine, "myFakeIP");
            }
          };
        }
      }));
      console.log("test finished")
    }
```

I hope my question is understandable and thank you for the help

[EDIT] that's my output :
[image]

[EDIT2] to simplify I want to test aMachine on A,B,C,D of `checkMyDataSources` and if there isn't aMachine in one of those cells (but at the end) then call `createDataSource()`

Comment: How about the use of `if {<String>.indexOf(<String2>) > -1}` ?

Comment: @reporter what is it going to do ?

Comment: I believe it would be better if you write clearly what your inputs are and what you expect your outputs to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const datasources = ["datasource_A", "datasource_B", "datasource_D", "datasource_C"];
const lesInfosMachines = ["A", "D", "C"];
const prefixLength = "datasource_".length
```

- If you want to get `datasources`which are **not** on `lesInfosMachines`:

  ```
  datasources.filter((d) => lesInfosMachines.every((l) => l !== d.slice(prefixLength)))
  ["datasource_B"]
  ```
- If you want to get `datasources`which **are** on `lesInfosMachines`:

  ```
  datasources.filter((d) => lesInfosMachines.some((l) => l === d.slice(prefixLength)))
  ["datasource_A", "datasource_D", "datasource_C"]
  ```
- If you want it to return `true`if there **are** some of the `datasources`in `lesInfosMachines`, and `false` otherwise:

  ```
  let otherLesInfosMachines = ["X", "Y", "Z"]

  datasources.some((d) => otherLesInfosMachines.some((l) => l === d.slice(prefixLength)))
  false

  datasources.some((d) => lesInfosMachines.some((l) => l === d.slice(prefixLength)))
  true
  ```

By combining functions such as [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filtro), [`every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every), and [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some), you can implement many algorithms very idiomatically, without having rely on difficult to understand, and even semantically meaningless, `for`loops and indexes.

Comment: Woaw it's very nice ! I'll try to use this method for other use case

Answer (score 2):

have you heard about [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#difference) ?

```
const _ = require('lodash');

let checkMyDataSources = ["datasource_A","datasource_B","datasource_D","datasource_C"];
let lesInfosMachines = ["A","B","C"];
_.difference(checkMyDataSources, _.map(lesInfosMachines, (elt) => 'datasource_' + elt));

>[ 'datasource_D' ]
```

Comment: No I have never heard something about that but it looks very interesting I'll take a look about it, I'm sure it could be helpful for some of my use case

Comment: it's not useful, it's essential :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of connecting the two loops, leading to multiple comparsions of the same element, you could use [`Array.prototype.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

This would make your code approximately look like this:

```
var lesInfosMachines = InfosMachines.find({});
if (checkMyDataSources.length < 1) {
    console.log("there is not datasource, we will create them all");
    callInitDS();
} else {
    console.log("there is datasource, we will check them");
    lesInfosMachines.forEach(Meteor.bindEnvironment(function(machineInfo) {
        console.log("test machine " + machineInfo.nameMachine);
        if (checkMyDataSources.includes("datasource_" + machineInfo.nameMachine) {
                console.log("Datasource:  " + machineInfo.nameMachine + " already exist.");
            } else {
                if (machineInfo.ipAddr != null) {
                    console.log("going to create " + machineInfo.nameMachine);
                    createDataSource(machineInfo.nameMachine, machineInfo.ipAddr);
                } else {
                    console.log("going to create " + machineInfo.nameMachine + " with a fake @ip because it was null ONLY FOR TESTING WE NEED TO REMOVE THIS");
                    createDataSource(machineInfo.nameMachine, "myFakeIP");
                }
            };
        }
    }));
    console.log("test finished")
}
```

Otherwise you would have to reorganize your loops as in Jeromes answer.

Comment: I'm Jerome ^^, I'll try to implement your solution it sounds better than mine

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution by using a `boolean` like this:

```js
var hasTestedAll = false;
var lesInfosMachines = InfosMachines.find({});
    if(checkMyDataSources.length < 1){
      console.log("there is not datasource, we will create them all");
      callInitDS();
    }else{
      console.log("there is datasource, we will check them");
      lesInfosMachines.forEach(Meteor.bindEnvironment(function(machineInfo) {
        console.log("test machine " + machineInfo.nameMachine)
        for (var i = 0; i < checkMyDataSources.length; i++) {
          console.log("test on " + checkMyDataSources[i].name.split("_")[1]);

              if(checkMyDataSources[i].name.split("_")[1] === machineInfo.nameMachine){
                if(i == checkMyDataSources.length-1){
                  hasTestedAll = true;
                }
                console.log("Datasource:  " + machineInfo.nameMachine + " already exist." );
              }else if(hasTestedAll){
                if(machineInfo.ipAddr != null){
                  console.log("going to create " + machineInfo.nameMachine);
                  createDataSource(machineInfo.nameMachine, machineInfo.ipAddr);
                }else{
                  console.log("going to create " + machineInfo.nameMachine + " with a fake @ip because it was null ONLY FOR TESTING WE NEED TO REMOVE THIS");
                  createDataSource(machineInfo.nameMachine, "myFakeIP");
                }
              };
        }
      }));
      console.log("test finished")
    }
```

(sorry for the CodeSnipet that doesn't work but I wasn't able to paste the code with a correct alignment)

So it test if I'm in the last cell of `checkMyDataSources` and if it's the case I allow to call the create method